# Installing png in CRAN 3.4.3

Tags: cran

I am trying to install the png package in CRAN 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 via

```
install.packages("png", dependencies=TRUE)
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/steve/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) trying URL 'https://cran.uni-muenster.de/src/contrib/png_0.1-7.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 24990 bytes (24 KB)
    ================================================== downloaded 24 KB

* installing *source* package ‘png’ ...
** package ‘png’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      `libpng-config --cflags` -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong
-Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c read.c -o read.o gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      `libpng-config --cflags` -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong
-Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c write.c -o write.o gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o png.so read.o write.o -L/home/steve/anaconda2/lib -lpng16 -lm -lz -lm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR installing to /home/steve/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/png/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘png’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  unable to load shared object '/home/steve/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/png/libs/png.so':   libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Error: loading failed Execution halted ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/steve/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/png’

The downloaded source packages are in   ‘/tmp/Rtmp4L5Eco/downloaded_packages’ Warning message: In install.packages("png", dependencies = TRUE) :   installation of package ‘png’ had non-zero exit status
```

Do you have an idea how to fix it?